# How do I execute my rails app after issuing a bundle --deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I understand that running the above command will install all of the gems necessary for my rails app to work properly into `vendor/bundle`. I believe I should then be able to copy the entire app directory to any system that has a compatible version of Ruby running on it and run my app without having to install the gems at a system or user level.

My question is, how do I actually execute that app? From what I gather, I should be able to run:

`bundle exec rails s`

For the app to look internally for the gems rather than looking to the system to supply them. But, I get the error:

`bundler: command not found: rails`

I'd like to be able to do this without altering the PATH variable on the host system if possible.

Comment: Have you tried `bin/rails s`? Note you don't run the built-in Rails server in production, you use something like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) for hosting.

Comment: there is a hidden folder .bundle/config holding that information. Do you have it ?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a `.bundle` directory in my project at all. It does seem like everything has been downloaded into the `vendor/bundle` directory however.